# Drag and drop is not working with selenium 3.0 + chrome 65

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium3

**Drag and drop is not working with selenium 3.0 + chrome 65**

**Page**:- http://thetestingworld.com/testings/dashboard.php

registration is free over site

i'm facing an diffculity to perform drag and drop here, already used JS executer and normal dragAndDrop() still not able to perform

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5429 perhaps

Comment: Thanks Michael for quick response!, but is there any way to make it possible

Comment: It looks like it's a known issue, but some workarounds have been posted here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604

Answer (score 1):

I was able to perform drag and drop using the following snippet:

```
_js.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).simulate('drag-n-drop',{dragTarget:arguments[1],interpolation:{stepWidth:100,stepDelay:50}});", _sourceElement, _targetElement);
```

You can read more and download the necessary JS files from [this link](https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext).